# How to implement permission validation in a simple way in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP. In JavaEE, a interceptor can be used to simplify the permission validation. After you implement and configure the interceptor, the validation will be automatically run before business logic. Is there a simple way to implement this function in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a "raw" language, PHP itself doesn't have any permissions system, but most (if not all) PHP frameworks do; so I'd recommend starting with a framework like ZF, Symfony or CodeIgniter. If you're coming frpm a Java background, I'd expect you're already familiar with MVC.